# How can I retrieve and loop through data retrieved from a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I am using an open-source api to retrieve breweries when people search by city name. I can console. log the promise returned but when I try to loop and console.log the data it tells me undefined.

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('beer-search-button');

const getBeerData = (cityName) => {
    const beerApi = `https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=${cityName}`;
    encodeURI(beerApi);
    fetch(beerApi)
    .then(res => {
        if(res.ok) {
            console.log(res.json());
            for(let b in res) {
                console.log(b.name);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Error!');
        }
    });
}

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    let searchQuery = document.getElementById('city-input').value;
    
    getBeerData(searchQuery);
});
```

Comment: `b` is always a string, which does not have a `name` property. So it's undefined.
Use `for(let b in res){ console.log(res[b] ) }` to show the values. But I guess it's not what you want. Instead, you want to read the result of `res.json()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the result of `res.json()`. You do this with another `.then()`.

And calling `encodeURI()` without using the result has no effect. You should be calling `encodeURIComponent()` on the city name, and using that in the URI.

```js
const getBeerData = (cityName) => {
  const beerApi = `https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=${encodeURIComponent(cityName)}`;
  fetch(beerApi)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json()
      } else {
        throw "Error";
      }
    }).then(res => res.forEach(b => console.log(b.name)));
}
```

Comment: might want to add that the encodeURI is not doing anything and probably wants to be included in the beerApi declaration around the cityName

Answer (score 0):

`res.json()` also returns a Promise which you need to await either using `then()` or using `await` which is certainly my preferred option.

Please note that there is no need to URL encode the whole string as the API's URL is already encoded correctly, so you just need to URI encode the city name. Another thing you should probably do, is wait for the DOM to be loaded using [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) before assigning event listeners as otherwise problems could occur because the DOM element might not yet be present.

```js
const getBeerData = async (cityName) => {
  const beerApi = `https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=${encodeURIComponent(cityName)}`;
  const res = await fetch(beerApi);
  if (res.ok) {
    const breweries = await res.json();
    breweries.forEach(brewery => console.log(brewery));
  } else {
    console.log("Error!");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  const searchBtn = document.getElementById("beer-search-button");

  searchBtn.addEventListener("click", async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    let searchQuery = document.getElementById("city-input").value;
  
    await getBeerData(searchQuery);
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="city-input" name="city-input">
<button id="beer-search-button">Search for breweries!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've logged the promise but you haven't parsed that JSON. You can't loop over an array if it doesn't exist. And, because it's an array you should be using a [for/of loop `for (const b of data)...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement).

Here's a shortened version.

```js
// Get the data
fetch(beerApi)

  // Parse the data
  .then(res => res.json())

  // Loop over the data
  .then(data => {
    for (const b of data) {
      console.log(b.name);
    }

  });

});
```